# How to install Plasma 5.4 on Kubuntu

Tags: kubuntu, plasma

Can anyone tell how to upgrade Kubuntu 15 plasma to 5.4?
I found these commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kubuntu-ppa/backports
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

But after restart I still have plasma 5.3. Even in Help -> About System Settings I see version 5.3.2. What else I need to do, to upgrade plasma version?

Comment: welcome to askubuntu. try after you do this two steps, do a "sudo apt-get install kubuntu-desktop" without the ".

Comment: After this command, I still have the same version.

Comment: ops :D, so i have no idea now

Answer (score 2):

Use this tuto:

> 1. Add [Kubuntu CI Stable PPA](https://launchpad.net/~kubuntu-ci/+archive/ubuntu/stable):
>
>    ```
>    sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kubuntu-ci/stable
>    ```
>
>    If you’ve added [Kubuntu backports PPA](https://launchpad.net/~kubuntu-ppa/+archive/ubuntu/backports/), and it does not yet update with
>      Plasma 5.4. You may remove it via:
>
>    ```
>    sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:kubuntu-ppa/backports
>    ```
> 2. Update system cache and upgrade your system:
>
>    ```
>    sudo apt-get update
>    sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
>    ```
>
> If you’re not in Kubuntu, you may run below command to install KDE:
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get install plasma-desktop
> ```
>
> If everything goes well, restart your computer to apply changes.

Source:  [ubuntuhandbook.org](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2015/08/install-kde-plasma-plasma-5-4/)

Answer (score 0):

You can check [Kubuntu Backports](https://launchpad.net/~kubuntu-ppa/+archive/ubuntu/backports/+index?field.series_filter=&batch=75&direction=backwards&memo=900&start=825) to see when `plasma-desktop` is upgraded to 5.4.
Just search for **plasma-desktop** on the page.

You might also want to read [How to Install KDE Plasma 5.4 in (K)Ubuntu 15.04](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2015/08/install-kde-plasma-plasma-5-4/), especially for the part on how to uninstall the backports ppa if anything goes wrong. I needed that in the past. ;)